# Phonegap device AMD module

Tags: cordova, durandal, amd, durandal-2.0

Here is my code which suppose to handle device and network events for my phonegap application

```
define(['jquery', 'knockout'], function ($, ko) {
var deviceHandler = {
    Online: null,
    Offline: null,
    OnNavigateBack: null
};

function HandleBackClick() {
    return deviceHandler.OnNavigateBack;
}

function HandleOnlineState() {
    return deviceHandler.Online;
}

function HandleOfflineState() {
    return deviceHandler.Offline;
}

document.addEventListener('online', HandleOnlineState, false);
document.addEventListener('offline', HandleOfflineState, false);
document.addEventListener('backbutton', HandleBackClick, false);

return deviceHandler;
});
```

When I import this module I assign my own function to devicecs online event in this way

```
MobileDevice.Online = function() {
            alert("we have updated information..");
        };
```

but it never gets called. can anyone help me with this module? one more thing to not: this assignment is differently called after device ready event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't calling your event handlers -- you are returning references instead. Try this:

```
function HandleBackClick() {
    return deviceHandler.OnNavigateBack();
}
function HandleOnlineState() {
    return deviceHandler.Online();
} 
function HandleOfflineState() {
    return deviceHandler.Offline();
}
```

Of course, you should handle cases where you may not have a handler defined or where you have parameters being sent. I've made it a bit more generic as well, but you can ignore that if you want.

```
function _callEventHandler ( eventHandler ) {
    var handler;
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1); // skip the first parameter
    if (typeof deviceHandler[eventHandler] !== "undefined") {
        handler = deviceHandler[eventHandler];
        if (typeof handler === "function") {
            handler.apply (this, args);
        } else {
            console.log ( "WARNING: event handler isn't a function", eventHandler );
        }
    } else {
        console.log ( "WARNING: event handler isn't defined", eventHandler );
    }
}

// a bit more generic so you can add events easily without duplicating a lot of code
// down the line. Of course, it might be better to simply register for the event
// when the handler is assigned -- you could use properties for that
[ [ "online", "Online" ],
  [ "offline", "Offline" ],
  [ "backbutton", "OnNavigateBack" ] 
].forEach ( function ( evt )
    {
        document.addEventListener ( evt[0], _callEventHandler.bind(this, evt[1]), false );
    }
);

// if you don't want to be that generic you can still:
// document.addEventListener ( "online", _callEventHandler.bind(this, "Online"), false );
// ...
```

Comment: ok thank u very much it works now the only question I have is, how can I add multiply handlers so that all of them are called once event is fired?

Comment: Use arrays, push and splice, and then iterate through each array when an event is received. Make sure to use `try...catch` to continue to further handlers when one handler is broken (for whatever reason). I like to wrap my handler calls with `setTimeout` as well.

Comment: could you please edit my code in a way that supports functionality you mentioned?